# Establishing SSE connection over https fails

Tags: https, server-sent-events

As far as I have understood, to establish an event stream one must create an event source object on the client passing it an endpoint to the server to register itself with. The server upon receiving this request, sets the response headers appropriately and sends data following the event stream format. I have this flow set up and it works over http but after adding SSL to the server, the event stream is getting created and the server throws a 501 - Not implemented error. After some research, I assumed it might be a CORS issue and added the appropriate headers but that didn't make a difference either. I have also tried small fixes that usually work for 501 errors like clearing browser cache and disabling any proxy settings. I'm completely puzzled by this and would really appreciate if somebody could help me understand the problem and best way to fix it.

**EDIT:**

The client sends a request to the server through aws elb load balancer that strips off ssl from requests and forwards requests to the server. The other possible reason for the server to throw a 501 error apart from CORS related issues is that the request was altered.

- Is it possible that when the load balancer removes SSL from the requests before forwarding it to the server, it alters sse requests in some way causing the server to throw the error? How would one monitor the requests coming in to the load balancer and the requests being forwarded?

Also, upon further research I have understood that internally Server Side Events are essentially a form of HTTP Streaming. The request is kept open even after data is sent until it is explicitly closed by the client. Considering that my first hunch is wrong, the SSL is stripped off and forwarded to the server without altering the request and the server sends the response headers and also heartbeat signals to keep the connection alive.

- Does that mean the stream is also encrypted?

The server is written in Koa. Here's what the sse registration endpoint looks like:

```
router.get("/api/sse/register/*", async (ctx: Router.IRouterContext) => {
        const i = ctx.path.lastIndexOf("/");
        const asset: string = ctx.path.slice(18, i);
        const orgId: string = ctx.path.slice(i + 1);
        let assetObj: any = myCache.get(asset);

        // setting headers to specify event stream connection
        ctx.set({
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
            "Content-Type" : "text/event-stream; charset=utf-8",
            "Cache-Control" : "no-cache",
            "Connection" : "Keep-Alive",
            "Transfer-encoding": "identity",
        });
        ctx.status = 200;
        ctx.flushHeaders();

        /* Creating pass through stream that simply pipes input given to it to its assigned output stream which in this case is ctx.body*/
        const stream = new PassThrough();
        ctx.body = stream;
        // saving mapping between orgId and its stream object to push data to
        assetObj[orgId] = stream;
        myCache.set(asset, assetObj);
        sendHeartbeatSignal(orgId, asset, assetObj);
 }
```

Also here's what the client side of the sse transaction looks like:

```
const source = new EventSource("/api/sse/register/trailers/" + org.id);
source.addEventListener("message", (event: any) => this.onUpdate(this, event));
```

Comment: Can you show an actual example. Or at least explain exactly how you solved CORS? Also, which server, and which OS/browsers have you tried with? And finally (for the moment!), was it a self-signed SSL certificate? (The browser question is the key one: does it fail in the same way in all browsers vs. just failing in one browser.)

Comment: I've written the server using koa and it's currently hosted on aws and I've only tried running it on Ubuntu and Chrome so far. The reason I haven't tried it out on different browsers is because I hadn't implemented the polyfill for sse to work in all browsers. I was just trying to get it to work on Chrome for now. And no, it's not a self signed certificate. It was deployed on the aws load balancer that sits between the client and the server instance

Comment: @DarrenCook I've included some code in the latest edit